# Group by and summarize conditionally

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, data-cleaning

My data table `df` shows employees, their employers, and whether they are hybrid workers. It looks like this:

```
name firm hybrid
Mike A    1
Kate A    1 
Dan  C    0
Jess B    0
Mick C    1
Nate C    0 
Mike A    1
```

I want to have a table that shows the number of employees and number of hybrid employees by firm:

```
firm total hybrid
A    3     3
B    1     0
C    3     1
```

What I tried so far is `group_by (firm) %>% summarize (total =  length(unique(name)), hybrid = length(unique(df[hybrid == 1])))`
However, this approach gave me one observation per employee instead of firm.
Does anyone know a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `name[hybrid == 1]` instead of `df[hybrid == 1]`. Note that `dplyr` has a wrapper function for `length(unique(x))`, `n_distinct`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(firm) %>% 
  summarise(total = n_distinct(name),
            hybrid = n_distinct(name[hybrid == 1]))
```

output

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  firm  total hybrid
  <chr> <int>  <int>
1 A         2      2
2 B         1      0
3 C         3      1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(df1)[, .(total = uniqueN(name), hybrid = uniqueN(name[hybrid == 1])), firm]
     firm total hybrid
   <char> <int>  <int>
1:      A     2      2
2:      C     3      1
3:      B     1      0
```

Comment: Thanks for this interesting approach!